# Undefined variable: variable won't pass in another page

Tags: laravel

I'm facing a problem about passing a variable in another page in laravel from controller. it always shows me the same exception but i did everything and exact from tutorial. I'm using Laravel 5.8

this is my problem:

```
Undefined variable: pods (View: 
E:\work\practice\Test\resources\views\pods\index.blade.php)
```

my controller code:

```
public function index()
    {
        $pods = Pod::all();
        return view('pods.index', compact('pods'));
    }
```

my resource file:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title','Home')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <a href="{{ route('pods.create') }}" class="btn btn-uni"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Create New Pod</a>
    </div>

    <div class="container mt-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                 {{ $pods->name }}
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-9">
                <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
                    <div class="card card-body">
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

this is my route code:

```
   Route::get('/', function () { return view('pods.index'); }); 
   Auth::routes(); 
   Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index'); 
   Route::resource('pods','PodController');
```

Please give a solution for my problem. Thank you.

Comment: this is my route code:

    <?php
        Route::get('/', function () {
         return view('pods.index');
       });

       Auth::routes();

       Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
       Route::resource('pods','PodController');

Comment: because your index page return pods.index and in your index page controller you didnt pass $pods

Comment: @AbolfazlMohajeri how will i pass the variable ?
i triend it like that

      public function index()
           {
             $pods = Pod::all();
              return view('pods.index', ['pods' => $pods]);
          }

bt i was receiving same error as before

Comment: your first route in your web.php is the problem you should pass $pods in that too:Route::get('/', function () { $pods = Pod::all();
    return view('pods.index', compact('pods'));});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed a collection to your view you should iterate it like this:

```
@foreach($pods as $pod)
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
     {{ $pod->name }}
  </button>
@endforeach
```

or you can try:

```
public function index()
{
    $pods = Pod::first();
    return view('pods.index', compact('pods'));
}
```

Comment: I did it but nothing changed

Comment: same error as before.. my view isn't getting the value from my controller

Comment: @SalehAhmedSifat because your index page return pods.index and in your index page controller you didnt pass $pods

Comment: @SalehAhmedSifat you need to understand how routing works, or mvc concept at least, you had 2 routes leading to views/pods/index , which is '/' and 'pods' , and the controller you made is accessed via url 'pods', please access it via /pods , not '/'

Answer (score 0):

You are passing collection from controller so you either need to loop through the `pods` variable in your view or return a single pod from controller.

Hope it helps!